# Angular, can't resolve all parameters while trying to dynamically create a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically add a `BlockComponent` to a `GridLayoutComponent`, but I get this error `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BlockComponent: (?, [object Object])` when the page load, it come from the `addBlock` function of `GridLayoutComponent`. I have very little idea about how to dynamically add components in Angular, and all tutorial I saw were very simplistic, added components had no constructors. Here is my code:

**grid-layout.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { EditGridService } from '../edit-grid.service';
import { Block } from '../block/block.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid-layout',
  templateUrl: './grid-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid-layout.component.css']
})
export class GridLayoutComponent {
  @ViewChild('grid') grid;
  blocksWidth = 250;
  blocksHeight = 82;
  margin = 8;
  cols = 5;
  lines = 8;
  width = this.cols * this.blocksWidth + (this.cols + 1) * this.margin;
  height = this.lines * this.blocksHeight + (this.lines + 1) * this.margin;
  grid = []

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private editGridService: EditGridService) {
  }

  get viewClass() {
    return this.editGridService.edit
      ? 'visible'
      : '';
  }

  /**
   * Return the block coordinates corresponding to the pixel coordinates (x, y)
   * @param {number} x - x coordinate in pixel (example: event.clientX)
   * @param {number} y - y coordinate in pixel (example: event.clientY)
   * @return {object} {x: number, y: number} - coordinates of the block at the given position
   */
  getCoord(x: number, y: number) {
    let rect = this.grid.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    return {
      x: Math.floor((x - rect.x) / (this.blocksWidth + this.margin)),
      y: Math.floor((y - rect.y) / (this.blocksHeight + this.margin))
    }
  }

  arr(n, v=0) {
    return Array(n).fill(v)
  }

  addBlock(e: any) {
    let coord = this.getCoord(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    // It's the line below that cause the problem
    const b = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Block)
    let block = this.grid.createComponent(b)
    block.x = coord.x
    block.y = coord.y
  }
}
```

**block.components.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Host, Input, ViewChild, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GridLayoutComponent } from '../grid-layout/grid-layout.component';
import { EditGridService } from '../edit-grid.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'block',
  templateUrl: './block.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./block.component.css']
})
export class BlockComponent implements OnInit {
  parent : GridLayoutComponent;
  @Input() cols : number = 1;
  @Input() lines : number = 1;
  @Input() x : Integer = 0;
  @Input() y : Integer = 0;

  constructor(@Host() parent: GridLayoutComponent, private editGridService: EditGridService) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  set cols(v: any) {
    this._cols = typeof v == 'number'
      ? v
      : parseInt(v)
  }

  get cols(): number {
    return this._cols
  }

  set lines(v: any) {
    this._lines = typeof v == 'number'
      ? v
      : parseInt(v)
  }

  get lines(): number {
    return this._lines
  }

  get margin(): number {
    return this.parent.margin / 2;
  }

  get width(): number {
    return this.cols * this.parent.blocksWidth + (this.cols - 1) * this.parent.margin;
  }

  get height(): number {
    return this.lines * this.parent.blocksHeight + (this.lines - 1) * this.parent.margin;
  }

  get left(): number {
    return this.x * (this.parent.blocksWidth + this.parent.margin) + this.margin;
  }

  get top(): number {
    return this.y * (this.parent.blocksHeight + this.parent.margin);
  }

  startDrag(e: any) {
    this.editGridService.draggedBlock = this;
  }

  startResize(e: any) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    this.editGridService.resizedBlock = this;
  }
}
```

Also, the `grid` attribute of `GridLayoutComponent` doesn't have a `createComponent` method. Can you show me the right way to dynamically create a component in Angular and adds it to the page?

**EDIT:**
Non dynamically created `BlockComponent` work perfectly.
**grid-layout.component.html:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-wrapper" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': width, 'height.px': height}">
    <div class="grid-view" [ngClass]="viewClass">
      <div class="grid-view-cell" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': blocksWidth, 'height.px': blocksHeight, 'margin.px': margin / 2}"
      (mousedown)="addBlock($event)" *ngFor="let number of arr(cols * lines)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid" #grid>
      <!-- All the block below are working perfectly -->
      <block x="0" y="0">1</block>
      <block x="1" y="0" cols="3" lines="3">2</block>
      <block x="4" y="0" lines="3">3</block>
      <block x="0" y="1" lines="2">4</block>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**
My code is available on GitHub (https://github.com/FrancoisMentec/RiotApiChallenge2018) so you can normally access it on StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/github/FrancoisMentec/RiotApiChallenge2018)

**EDIT 3:**
I removed the `@Host` parameter to access the `GridLayoutComponent` from the `BlockComponent`, and get the `GridLayoutComponent` from an `EditGridService`. It's working but it doesn't feel like the right way to do this, there should be a solution to make a factory of a component having a `@Host` parameter.

Comment: Seems in your case it means that you have circular dependency. Check this out https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27546

Comment: For (dynamic components)[https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader]. Also did you provide `BlockComponent` as part of `entryComponents` array?

Comment: @yurzui when I comment the `addBlock` method my app works perfectly, I have multiple `BlockComponent` inside `grid-layout.component.html` and no problem. It's really the dynamic creation that isn't working.

Comment: @KiraAG I added `BlockComponent`to `entryComponents` inside app.module.ts, but nothing changed.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz version?

Comment: @KiraAG it's on GitHub (just pushed the last version) so normally you can access it on StackBlitz, I added the link to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The resolveComponentFactory expects here a component (see https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver):

```
const b = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Block)
```

Looking at the code `BlockComponent` is not a component but a simple class with a member `parent` which is a component but that does not constitute inheritance.

It strikes me also odd from a to export `BlockComponent` but to import `Block`.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a directive which makes the above process really easy, (ngComponentOutlet)

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="BlockComponent"></ng-container>
```

In App.module.ts file you need to add BlockComponent in entryComponents array. (Dont forget to import the BlockComponent in the ts file as well)

Above Work Can be done in a complicated way as well.
in HTML file add an ng-container

```
<ng-container #viewcontainer></ng-container>
```

In ts file add

```
@ViewChild('viewcontainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vc: ViewContainerRef;
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.vc.clear();
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlockComponent);
      const dynamicComponent = factory.create(this.vc.parentInjector);
      this.vc.insert(dynamicComponent.hostView);
  }
```

Both works same, first one easire, dont forget to add component to entry component array. All the best!!

You can read more at:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I still get the same error, I think the issue come from the @Host parameter of BlockComponent

Comment: @FrançoisMENTEC Hey, there is a great article on rendering components dynamically in angular, https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e I guess it will help, all the best

Comment: Didn't solve my problem, your solution and every other tutorial/guide work perfectly with other components, but having the `@Host` parameter in my BlockComponent make it fail. I need a way to handle component using @Host with ComponentFactoryResolver.

Comment: Not sure if it will work or not but if you need access to same component(Parent) use constructor (private hostElement: ElementRef) {},

this.hostElement will give access to the parent component
remove (@host parent: GridComponent) from contructor